# JavaFX (8) - Improving scatter chart performance

Tags: java, performance, charts, javafx-8

**Question:**

In what ways can I improve render-time in scenario described below?

**Description:**

The task I'm facing is plotting quite a few points on a scatter chart in JavaFX. I'm getting the data from an Oracle DB.

I think my current bottleneck is `scatterChart.getData().add(series);`

The `series` contains all the datapoints needed in the chart.

Executing this, and rendering the chart on screen may take anywhere from several seconds to several minutes. During this time the GUI freezes up.

We're running some Lenovo Thinkpads with 4 Cores 4 Threads, Intel HD4000 Graphics.

Some examples of finished charts are below. The latter being the current worst case, but as more data is collected, more data will be displayed.

(due to images being impractically large, only links)

[Chart with ~5.5K points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0gnW.png)
[Chart with ~75K points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgqGB.png)

**More info**

I followed [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/) because I'm new to JavaFX, so I'm not sure exactly how rendering happens.

**Code sample**

This isn't the actual code I'm using, it's just to illustrate how I'm doing things.

```
//Reference to the chart in the fxml file.
@FXML
private ScatterChart<Date, Number> scatterChart
= new ScatterChart<>(new DateAxis(), new NumberAxis());

private void handleSelectionUpdate(PerfResultSet newValue){
    //newValue is an object containing all the data from the database
    XYChart.Series<Date, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    /**
    *   adding all the data from newValue to series as 
    *   XYChart.Data<Date, Number>
    *
    *   this is handled by multiple threads and does not take long
    */

    series.setName("myName");


    //this statement is where the gui freezes
    //can I optimize this in any way?
    scatterChart.getData().add(series);
}
```

Comment: What is your code? Without any code, to see how you add and render the data we can't really help you. Also have you tested where the actual bottleneck is? Reading from database, adding to list, rendering to screen?
Are you rendering directly to screen or to an off screen buffer?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets please see more info I added

Comment: @Baurzhan's approach of plotting only representative points might work for you (though determining what is "representative" is not trivial in general). Just a note here that JavaFX charts are really not designed for large data sets like this. Each data point is represented by a node, with CSS styling and potentially user interactivity. You might just find it is easier to roll your own chart implementation for cases like this (e.g. drawing to a canvas).

Comment: @James_D just looked at it briefly, this would probably be better. The only thing not so nice about that would be having to do Axes yourself.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use the axis classes in conjunction with your own implementation of the plot. There are enough hooks in the API, such as `getDisplayPosition()` and `getValueForDisplay()` to make that feasible. Perhaps another possibility to consider is to subclass `XYChart` and implement `layoutPlotChildren()` just to draw a canvas, or similar.

Comment: I'll bodge around with this next week when I'm on holiday, thanks for the suggestion. I'll probably do a combination of @James_D's and Baurzhan's suggestions.

Comment: @Marin: I had the same performance problem. My JavaFX charts took minutes for rendering. In the end I switched to JFreeChart and render time went down to a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar problem - I was drawing route consisting of many points to google map with Javascript. I eliminated points taking to account current scale. I saw your png files, it seems **you really need ~30-50 points** for expressing the following message - hey, this vertical/horizontal segment contains so many points you may assume it solid line!

Next problem is max scale - I think, each solid line in 75K chart is actually not solid. I mean, in small scale, I see a lot points like solid line `____` but in max scale I see them as `. .    . ... .  ..` But usually, max scale required only for small piece of chart and **you may eliminate not by scale but by borders**. Again reference to google map - when you zoom the map, you are not seeing whole globe in cool resolution but some small piece of map. Other borders eliminated automatically.

Post here your code, some information about scale, zoom (do you have such feature?). If you haven't and your chart is always as in png files in link, you should iterate over each vertical or horizontal line, look for sequental points and replace, for example, 100 sequantal points to middle point of that 100 points. Instead of 100 experimentally find such X, that replacing **sequental** X points to one *middle-value-point* does not affect the resulting chart.

I repeat the main idea - There exist some X, such that drawing X **sequental** points equal to drawing 1 point in some fixed scale - many points does not give precision but simply "overwrites" each other due to scale and human eye limitations.

Some pseudocode for finding X if your scale is constant;

```
int MAGIC = 50; //change it on each run of your program! You have to find the best value
int counter=1; // points[0] taken as included in accumulating solid segment
int startIndex=0,endIndex;
ArrayList<Integer> compressedDatesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1;i<datesArray.length;i++){
  if(deltaBetweenDates(datesArray[i]-datesArray[i-1])==1){
     counter++;
     endIndex=i;
     if(counter==MAGIC){
       counter=0;
       compressedDatesArray.add(datesArray[{endIndex-startIndex)/2]);
       startIndex=endIndex+1;
     }
  }

}
```

Render compressedArray, see png. If result is bad - chnage MAGIC and repeat

**UPDATE**

You may *binary search* MAGIC -  try 5000, if still solid after comperssing 5000 points to one, try bigger value if not, try 2500 and so on... Humans also may binary search something=)))

Also, do not forget to remember Y value of point representing big segment. I mean, also declare `compressedY` and add correspinding Y of `datesArray[(endIndex-startIndex/2)]`

Comment: so, basically when I have points that overlap, or are very close to each other I should just merge them into a single point?

Comment: @Martin, copy pasting will not work - I didn't take to account border cases - I mean, `endIndex-startIndex)/2` should be carefully checked - even, odd, resetting counter to zero - I'm not sure may be should be counter=1 and startIndex=endIndex instead of coubter=0 and startIndex=endIndex+1. I just posted pseudocode with main idea, you have to play with border cases by yourself=)

Comment: got it, I can figure out the exact implementation on my own :)